# How to automate semicolon in Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog, prolog-toplevel

I am learning about Prolog in class and was shown a way to automatically press the semicolon key until there are no more solutions. I have tried searching on Google but I get examples using `findall` which is not what was shown. Are there any other ways to automatically press `;` in the Prolog shell?

For example, showing all the solutions without pressing `;` repeatedly.

```
X = one ;
X = two ;
X = three ;
X = four.
```

Comment: The toplevel of GNU Prolog permits this directly by pressing `a` in place of `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, using the `member/2` for exemplifying, is to use the `fail/0` predicate after the goal:

```
?- member(X, [1,2,3]), writeq(X), nl, fail.
1
2
3
false.
```

Comment: I should have been more clear in my post, I wanted all the solutions generated from calling a predicate `number(X)`. I do not have a list.

Comment: What do the numbers after `member` and `number` mean?

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel `member/2` means that `member` is a functor with 2 arguments. Also, Paulo's solution works even in your case. You just need to think it through: `my_predicate(X), writeq(X), nl. fail.`. `member(X, [1,2,3])` is just an example of a predicate call that generates multiple solutions for `X`.